# How to click android native button with javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, selenium

I need to click some button in native android app several times in a row(7) for unlock extended settings. I was trying to use Selenium WebDriver+Appium test, but there is a delay about 1-2 seconds between clicks. So its not working.

Now i'm trying to use javascript executor function for emulate seven clicks in a row without delay. But i can`t find right solution. How can i refer to native android button with id "some_button" correctly with javascript from my test?

Comment: Native app button?

Comment: Could you share your attempt which have you tried to click using JavascriptExecutor??